# Just pick main identifier of fields that are in a type by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, audit

I'm doing a audit class. For that I've two object of same type, but I don't know what type.
To audit I just need the properties that make sense in a human reading document.

So I just want the Name (or main identifier) of custom object props.

Example: If I've a department and I change the manager. I need to log just the new manager Name. "Manager: John - Bill"

So how can I list just the main properties?

**-- more about**
To define the main identifier I'm using a customAttribute:

```
[audit]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

So, I'm thinking in pick them from a list, that except the primitives, with:

```
var propsOfObject = objectToAudit.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propsOfObejct) {
    IEnumerable<FieldInfo> props = propertyInfo.GetType().GetFields().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof (AuditAttribute)));
    if (props.Count() > 0) {
        dicWithNameValue.Add(propertyInfo.GetType().FullName, props.First().GetValue(objectToAudit).ToString());
    }
}
```

right way?

Comment: Does your code work? If yes, then what are you asking? If no, what is the problem?

Comment: Doesn't work yet. I'm having problem with primitive objects of main object. My question aims to ask if my solution make sense or I'm reinventing wheel..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be like this

```
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> props = propertyInfo.GetType().GetFields()
                        .Where(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuditAttribute>());
```

`FieldInfo.Attributes` that you are trying to use returns an `enum` of type `FieldAttributes`  and is used for a different purpose. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldattributes.aspx).